# nvcc compilation error using thrust in CUDA 11.5

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I initially asked about an error when trying to compile a code including `<algorithm>`, but this was solved by adding a flag `-std=c++14`, as in `nvcc -std=c++14 test1.cu`. However, now I get the same error message when including something from `<thrust>`

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <thrust/extrema.h> // code compiles without this
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is

```
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:435:145: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
  435 |         function(_Functor&& __f)
      |                                                                                                                                                 ^ 
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:435:145: note:         ‘_ArgTypes’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:146: error: parameter packs not expanded with ‘...’:
  530 |         operator=(_Functor&& __f)
      |                                                                                                                                                  ^ 
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:146: note:         ‘_ArgTypes’
```

What is wrong here?

I use these versions.

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
- gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
- g++ (Ubuntu 9.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0

Comment: You claim to be using g++ 9.5 but the error shows g++11 standard library includes failing. Are you really sure that your g++9 installation isn’t broken?

Comment: @talonmies This could be the case. Is there anything I can do to resolve this? I tried g++ 11.3.0, but got exactly the same error.

Comment: The update you just posted is exactly a bug I met with this version of CUDA (also with gcc 11.3 on Ubuntu 22.04). I upgraded to 11.7 and it worked.

Comment: @Erel I tried CUDA 11.8, and finally it worked. Thanks a lot for letting me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a bug with the specific version of CUDA, as was pointed out in the comment. The combination of these versions solved the issue.

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Cuda compilation tools, release 11.8, V11.8.89
- gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
- g++ (Ubuntu 9.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0

Comment: I solved this in Ubuntu 22.04 by using nvcc 11.5 and GCC 10.5.0. (g++-10 package).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with these versions

```
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Nov_18_09:45:30_PST_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.5, V11.5.119
Build cuda_11.5.r11.5/compiler.30672275_0

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

after updating to nvcc 11.8, the problem was solved.